# Wilcoxon rank signed test, paired or non-paired test?

Tags: median, paired-data, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I have been trying to figure out, whether or not I should use a paired or a non-paired test. My question comes from the fact, that I am trying to get the pseudo median, in order to say that SBP is [x] percentage points better than GICS. This is the table:

[image]

from which I have been using the following R-code, where I get the following two pseudo medians:

```
PAIRED=FALSE
W = 94392000, p-value = 0.00009025
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
99 percent confidence interval:
 0.003050862 0.014974725
sample estimates:
difference in location 
           0.008972393
```

and

```
PAIRED=TRUE
V = 48485000, p-value = 0.00000002249
    alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
    99 percent confidence interval:
     0.00768364 0.02082407
    sample estimates:
    (pseudo)median 
        0.01426058
```

Now, I am a bit confused as to which test to use. I am under the impression, that since the absolute difference between the two sample medians (24.3% and 23.4%) is 0.9%, the pseudo median can NEVER be larger than this 0.9%, which leads me to using the paired=false argument.

The way the data is structured is, that it contains 1500 firms across 15 years. The GICS and SBP selects groups of 10 differently, where they give an estimate of a financial variable (EV/EBITDA). This however, would indicate that I should use the paired test, as the observations from both samples are identical?

Would be very helpful if someone could explain if my thinking is correct in this matter, or not.